# Validation fails on dropdown list input item

Tags: yii

Friends,

I have a registration form with several items and the drop down list on these items seems like its not being picked up by the form submission.

**The View:**

```
 </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'Gjinia'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('sex', 0, $data = array(0 => 'Mashkull', 1 => 'Femer'))
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'Arsimimi'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('education', 0, $data = array(0 => 'Ulet', 1 => 'Mesem', 2 => 'Larte')) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'Statusi Martesor'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('marital_status', 0, $data = array(0 => 'Beqar/e', 1 => 'I/E divorcuar', 2 => 'I/E martuar', 3 => 'I/E veje')) ?>
    </div>
```

**Validation rules:**

```
public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('name, lastname, sex, education, 
                marital_status, employment, 
                dob, municipality, address, 
                cell_no, email, initialPassword, 
                repeatPassword', 'required'),
            array('sex, employment, municipality,', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('email, initialPassword, repeatPassword, name, lastname', 'length', 'max' => 100),
            array('initialPassword, repeatPassword', 'required', 'on' => 'insert'),
            array('initialPassword, repeatPassword', 'length', 'min' => 6, 'max' => 40),
            array('initialPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'repeatPassword'),
        );
    }
```

After submitting my form I am getting the following when I do a print_r on $_POST['Auser']:

```
Array ( [name] => Name [lastname] => Lname [address] => B ellit 
[cell_no] => 044 568 178 [email] => gzzi@gmail.com [id] => [sex] => 
[education] => [marital_status] => [employment] => [industry] => [dob] => 
[municipality] => [password] => )
```

and the error message:

```
Sex cannot be blank. 
Education cannot be blank.  
Marital Status cannot be blank. 
Employment cannot be blank. 
Dob cannot be blank.
Municipality cannot be blank.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dropdownlist should be defined like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'Statusi Martesor'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'marital_status', array(0 => 'Beqar/e', 1 => 'I/E divorcuar', 2 => 'I/E martuar', 3 => 'I/E veje')) ?>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'Statusi Martesor'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('marital_status', 0, $data = array(0 => 'Beqar/e', 1 => 'I/E divorcuar', 2 => 'I/E martuar', 3 => 'I/E veje')) ?>
</div>
```

In the first instance (where I used `CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'attribute_name')`), you can access your dropdown attributes after doing `$model->attributes = $_POST['ModelName'];` like this `$model->sex`, `$model->marital_status` because the POST array is ging to be like: `$_POST['ModelName']['sex']`, `$_POST['ModelName']['marital_status']`

When you use `CHtml::dropDownList('field_name', 'selected_value', array('option1', 'option2'))`, the POST array is of the form `$_POST['field_name']` and for ActiveRecord, what you want is `$_POST['ModelName']['field_name']`

I hope that solves your question.

Comment: Great answer but this way I am having the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and the problem seems to be with the data part:
array(0 => 'Beqar/e', 1 => 'I/E divorcuar', 2 => 'I/E martuar', 3 => 'I/E veje'))
any ideas?

Comment: Ok I fixed it the issue is that there should be no select value on the activeDropDownList:
It should be like this:

    <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'marital_status', array(0 => 'Beqar/e', 1 => 'I/E divorcuar', 2 => 'I/E martuar', 3 => 'I/E veje')) ?>
Thank you

Comment: Glad I was able to help